# Computing an integral via integration by parts

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Good afternoon,

I am learning for Monday's test and I stuck on this example:

$$  \int  (2x+3) \, \cos{2x} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

and I am asked to determine this integral. I am trying to do it by integration by parts, but it still leads me nowhere… Could you guys help me out with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=2x+3$, $dv=\cos(2x)\,dx$ so that $du=2\,dx$, $v={1\over 2}\sin(2x)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\int (2x+3)\cos(2x)\,dx&=(2x+3)\cdot{1\over 2}\sin(2x)-\int {1\over 2}\sin(2x)\cdot 2\,dx\\
&=(2x+3)\cdot{1\over 2}\sin(2x)-\int \sin(2x)\,dx\\
&=(2x+3)\cdot{1\over 2}\sin(2x)+{1\over 2}\cos(2x)+C.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much. How easy it looks like...